# What is the difference between `docker-compose` commands `down`, `kill` and `stop`?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to know, which command of `docker-compose` I have to use in which case, `down`, `kill` and `stop`? What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 7):

As documentation of [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/) says:

- [docker-compose down](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images created by [docker-compose up](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/),
- [docker-compose kill](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/kill/) forces running containers to stop by sending a SIGKILL signal,
- [docker-compose stop](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/stop/) stops running containers without removing them, so they can be started again with [docker-compose start](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/start/).

So, if you can wait for a while, and you want to do a simple, "hot" restart, without removing or disabling Docker infrastructure elements (like containers or networks), you should use **docker-compose stop**. This is the least invasive option.

If you hurry up, and you don't want to wait for a graceful stop operation, but you also don't want to remove containers, you should use **docker-compose kill**. The container stops working, but it is ready to be started again.

And if you are not interested in preserving containers at all, you can use **docker-compose down**. This scenario is a kind of "cold" restart.

Note that you can also use [docker-compose pause](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/pause/), which pauses running containers of service, so they are not stopped (like in the command mentioned above), and they can be unpaused with [docker-compose unpause](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/unpause/).

Comment: (In practice, I don't feel like "pause" or "stop" are really useful; it's cleaner and more Dockery to stop, delete, and recreate containers to restart them from a clean slate.  Also note that re-running "up" will recreate any containers whose configuration has changed in the `docker-compose.yml`.)

Comment: Why copy/paste existing documentation to StackOverflow? That is not the point of this web.

Comment: @AlexKarshin, I couldn't find the answer like this, and this ink confirms, that I can document knowledge gathered by myself: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer . And, btw, this is not copy/paste, your opinion is not valid.

Comment: @GerardJaryczewski excellant reference here. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

From Gerad answer, if you consider a container as running OS (e.g. Windows) those commands can be mapped to:

- pause (unpause) -> hibernate
- kill -> soft shut-down
- stop (start,restart) -> hard shut-down (by unplugging the system)
- down (up,create) -> factory reset

Comment: I see `stop` as a soft shutdown - it lets the containers to stop gracefully. But `kill` stops them immediately without any time to do a proper shutdown.